# Starting osm2po without parsing osm.pbf?

Tags: osm2po

I use the demo batch to start osm2po

```
java -Xmx1408m -jar osm2po-core-5.0.0-signed.jar prefix=hh tileSize=x,c map.osm.pbf
```

How can i start the webserver without parsing all the data again (because i think it only needs to be done once)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "cmd=r" option (r stands for routing):

```
java -Xmx1408m -jar osm2po-core-5.0.0-signed.jar prefix=hh cmd=r
```